# how to get plain but formated html using mechanize/nokogiri?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri, mechanize

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'mechanize'

  rational = Mechanize.new { |agent|
        agent.user_agent_alias = 'Windows Mozilla'
  }
  results = rational.get(ARGV[0])
  puts results.content
```

gives me **html** but I want **plain text**. The best would be if it can be formatted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This code will give you plain unformatted text of the entire document:

```
require 'mechanize'
require 'nokogiri'

rational = Mechanize.new { |agent|
    agent.user_agent_alias = 'Windows Mozilla'
}

document = Nokogiri::HTML(rational.get(ARGV[0]).content)

#This will give you very dirty result
#results = document.inner_text

#My suggestion is to extract text from some specific element
results = document.css("#content .my-element-with-some-contents").inner_text
```

Comment: works nicely. Thank you. I thought that I can use Nokogiri methods on Mechanize objects....

Comment: No need to parse response, you can write it like `rational.get(link); rational.page.at('/html/body/h1').text`